# What was in the Ark of the Covenant?

Tags: ark-aron-kodesh

[Shemot 25:21 says](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9886#v=21):

> And you shall place the ark cover on the ark from above, and **into the ark you shall place the testimony**, which I will give you.

This seems to be reaffirmed in [Melachim I 8:9](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15892#v=9):

> There was **nothing in the ark save the two tablets of stone** which Moses put there at Horeb, when the Lord made (a covenant) with the children of Israel, when they came out of the land of Egypt.

But the Christian scriptures say that at some point there was more. [Hebrews 9:4 says](http://biblehub.com/hebrews/9-4.htm):

> This ark contained the gold jar of manna, Aaron's staff that had budded, and the stone tablets of the covenant.

Since Hebrews was probably written by a Jew, and was definitely written *to* Jews, it would seem strange to me if this notion was different from Jewish thinking of the time of writing.

So do any Orthodox Jewish sources say either that there was only the testimony, or that there were other items?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**What was in the Ark?**

The Talmud teaches us ([Shekalim 16a](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00881.html#HtmpReportNum0028_L2) and [Bava Basra 14a](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00907.html#HtmpReportNum0024_L2)) that the Ark contained both sets of Tablets (the broken ones and the 2nd set) as well as the Torah Scroll the Moses wrote.

> **וארבעה לוחות היו בו שנים שלמים ושנים שבורים** דכתיב {דברים י-ב} אשר שברת ושמתם בארון הלוחות היו כל אחד וא' ארכו ו' טפחים רחבו (שלשה) ששה ותן ארכן של לוחות לאורכו של ארון נשתייר שם שלשה טפחים תן מהם חצי טפח לכל כותל **נשתייר שני טפחים לספר תורה**

Though there are opinions (in [Shekalim 16a](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00881.html#HtmpReportNum0028_L2)) that the first (broken) set of tablets were in a separate Ark.

> תני רבי יהודה (בר אילעי) בן לקיש אמר **ב' ארונות היו מהלכין עם ישראל במדבר אחד שהיתה התורה נתונה בתוכו ואחד שהיו שברי לוחות נתונין בתוכו** זה שהיתה התורה נתונה בתוכו היה מונח באהל מועד הדא הוא דכתיב {במדבר יד-מד} וארון ברית ה' ומשה לא משו מקרב המחנה זה שהיו שברי לוחות נתונין בתוכו היה נכנס ויוצא עמהן ופעמים שהיה מתראה עמהן ‏

**What was not in the Ark?**

The Rambam's opinion is that the jar of Man and Aaron's staff were placed next to the Ark.

See Ch 4. of  [הלכות בית הבחירה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_02001.html#HtmpReportNum0003_L2):

> **א:** אֶבֶן הָיְתָה בְּקֹדֶשׁ הַקָּדָשִׁים בְּמַעֲרָבוֹ שֶׁעָלֶיהָ הָיָה הָאָרוֹן מֻנָּח. **וּלְפָנָיו צִנְצֶנֶת הַמָּן וּמַטֵּה אַהֲרֹן**.‏

The Rambam's source is the Talmud in [Krisus 5b](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01121.html#HtmpReportNum0007_L2), [Yoma 52b](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00853.html#HtmpReportNum0101_L2), [Horius 12a](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01027.html#HtmpReportNum0020_L2).

That also seems to be the accepted translation of the verse in [Exodus 16:33](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01425_part_4.html#HtmpReportNum0003_L2)

> **לג:**  וַיֹּאמֶר מֹשֶׁה אֶל אַהֲרֹן קַח צִנְצֶנֶת אַחַת וְתֶן שָׁמָּה מְלֹא הָעֹמֶר מָן וְהַנַּח אֹתוֹ לִפְנֵי ה' לְמִשְׁמֶרֶת לְדֹרֹתֵיכֶם:‏
>
> And Moses said to Aaron, Take one jug and put there an omerful of manna, and deposit it before the Lord to be preserved for your generations

Rashi (ibid) agrees:

> **והנח אותו לפני ה'**. לפני הארון

Comment: Rabbi Yehuda argues that the Torah Scroll was to the side of the ark.

Comment: @SkinnyJ - According to the Bavli, but not the Yerushlami.

Comment: If possible, English translations of all the Hebrew quotes would be really really awesome.