# Of all Aron measures, why the thickness of the Kapores was not mentioned?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, shiurim-measurements, ark-aron-kodesh

While working on ["the-holy-ark-weigh-4-tons"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/99733/does-the-holy-ark-weigh-4-tons) I noticed, the thickness of the Kapores (1 Tefach) is concluded only in the Gemmorah by גזירה שווה to other measures ([Succa 5a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sukkah.5a.5?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)):

> "... אלא כפורת טפח מנלן? דתני רבי חנינא כל הכלים שעשה משה נתנה בהן תורה מדת ארכן ומדת רחבן ומדת קומתן כפורת מדת ארכה ומדת רחבה נתנה מדת קומתה לא נתנה "

Why the Torah, listing all other measures of the Aron<sup>1</sup> skips this one?

---

<sup>1</sup> I would like to hear if you can spot other missing measures in the Mishkan.

Comment: If I recall correctly, it doesn't list the measurements of the מנורה, either.

Answer (score -1):

The Torah doesn’t have any extra words. If we can figure out the thickness without the extra words, the words aren’t needed

Comment: Those are blind assumptions, not conclusions. Just about everything else in the Torah can be "logically" derived from other sources, and still we have other measurements.

Comment: Can you give an example of that?