# why were the measurements of the kiyor not given?

Tags: shiurim-measurements, mishkan-tabernacle, utensil

the measurements of all the other utensils in the mishkan are provided except for those of the kiyor. why were the measurements of the kiyor not given?

Comment: https://torah.org/torah-portion/rabbis-notebook-5764-kisisa/

Comment: The measurements of the Menorah weren’t given in the passuk either.

Comment: Similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/100018/759