Thickness of the walls of the Ark?
Is there a source brought on the thickness of the walls of the Aron ha-Brit? (Not the kapporet and not the dimensions of the walls FYI[which is in the p'shat] in case that's confusing.)

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/99733/759

Bava Basra 14a records two opinions regarding the thickness of the walls of the Ark. R’ Meir’s opinion is that the thickness was a 1/2 handbreadth. According to R’ Yehudah the walls were 1/4 handbreadth thick.

I wonder how that plays with the layered boxes!

I'm only wondering about the layered boxes not sure where to find a source on that tradition: but that would actually affect the shape!

@הראל Rashi on Shemot 25:10 states “Bezalel made three arks” and that they were placed one inside each other. “Bezalel made three arks, two of gold and one of wood, each having four walls (sides) and a bottom, being, however, open at the top. He put the wooden ark into the larger golden one and the smaller golden one into that of wood”
Rashi’s view is based on Yoma 72b – see Sefaria Yoma 72b:4 at https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.72b.4?lang=bi and Yerushalmi Shekalim 6:1 see Sefaria Yerushalmi Shekalim 6:1:14 https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Shekalim.6.1.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

@הראל If you like my answer, please consider accepting it. Otherwise, please comment on how it can be improved.

Okay, figuring out how the layered boxes really work in real life almost seems like extra-credit for a Navi. I'll accept your answer.
